# Error 'OpenAsTextStream' on type 'FileSystemObject' not found in ASPX

Tags: asp.net, xml, api, asp-classic

Trying to simply grab an XML file and spit its contents through an API onto a website.  This worked in the past and am now revisiting its code.  I am receiving the error:

> Public member 'OpenAsTextStream' on type 'FileSystemObject' not found.

Here is all of code:

```
    <%@ Page Title="MAIN" Language="vb" Explicit="true" AspCompat="true" %>

<% 

    Dim objFSO, objStream, ProductStr, ProdCodestr, ProdPricestr, xml_to_send, x
    x = 1

    objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim Filepath
    Filepath = Server.MapPath("sample.xml")       

    objStream = objFSO.OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    Do Until objStream.AtEndOfStream

        ' create the Xml that the Msxml2.serverXmlHttp object will send to the Webservice
        ProductStr = objStream.readline(x)
        ProdCodestr = ProductStr.substr(0, ",")
        ProdPricestr = ProductStr.substr(",", )
        xml_to_send = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>"
        Xml_to_Send = Xml_to_Send & "<xmldata>"
        Xml_to_Send = Xml_to_Send & "     <products>"
        xml_to_send = xml_to_send & "          <ProductCode>" & ProdCodestr & "</ProductCode>"
        xml_to_send = xml_to_send & "          <ProductPrice>" & ProdPricestr & "</ProductPrice>"
        xml_to_send = xml_to_send & "     </products>"
        xml_to_send = xml_to_send & "</xmldata>"

        x = x + 1
    Loop
    objStream.Close()
    objStream = Nothing
    objFSO = Nothing

    ' create the Msxml2.serverXmlHttp object needed to post the Xml to the WebService
    Dim oXMLHttp
    oXMLHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.serverXmlHttp")
    oXMLHttp.open("POST", "http://www.mywebsite.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=my@email.com&EncryptedPassword=xxx&Import=Update", False)
    oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")
    oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Action", "xmldata")
    oXMLHttp.setTimeouts(100000, 100000, 600000, 9999999)
    Server.ScriptTimeout = 10800

    ' Send the Xml  
    oXMLHttp.Send()

    ' Receive the Xml
    Dim Xml_Returned
    Xml_Returned = oXMLHttp.responseText

    ' Validate the Xml
    Dim xmlDoc
    xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
    xmlDoc.loadXML(Xml_Returned)
    If (Len(xmlDoc.text) = 0) Then
        Xml_Returned = ("<B>ERROR in Response xml:<BR>ERROR DETAILS:</B><BR><HR><BR>") & Xml_Returned
    End If

    ' Display the Xml on the browser
    Response.Write(Xml_Returned)

    ' clean up
    xml_to_send = Nothing
    oXMLHttp = Nothing
    Xml_Returned = Nothing
    xmlDoc = Nothing
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`OpenTextFile`](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_opentextfile.asp). BTW, the first parameter is the filename.

Comment: Thank you but I think it needs to be a Stream as it is sending to a webservice.

Comment: It does return [`TextStream`](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_textstream.asp). Are you looking for a specific functionality that it is missing?